# cocos2d HD assets not properly respecting the -hd suffix (@2x works fine)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have the files `progress_bar_bk.png` and `progress_bar_bk-hd.png`, which are 50x100 and 100x200 pixels, respectively, in my project.

When start the app on a regular (non retina) iPhone, or on Mac OSX, and print out `sprite.contentSize` it shows {50,100} as-expected.

When I start the app on a retina iPhone 5, it shows the content size as {25,50}, a mere half of the regular resolution!

Even weirder, if I rename `progress_bar_bk-hd.png` to `progress_bar_bk@2x.png` it works fine. That is, the resolution is {50,100} and it looks clean and crisp.

I've even gone so far as to try this:

    `CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:YES];
    [sharedFileUtils.suffixesDict setValue:@"-hd" forKey:kCCFileUtilsiPhoneHD];
    [sharedFileUtils.suffixesDict setValue:@"-hd" forKey:kCCFileUtilsiPhone5HD];
    [sharedFileUtils.suffixesDict setValue:@"-hd" forKey:kCCFileUtilsiPadHD];
    [sharedFileUtils.suffixesDict setValue:@"-hd" forKey:kCCFileUtilsMacHD];`

Still, cocos2d doesn't seem to respect the `-hd` suffix.

Comment: Do you have the Default-568h@2x.png file in your project ?

Comment: @giorashc I'm using a `LaunchImage.launchimage`, which does contain a `Default-568h@2x.png`. What does this have to do with it?

Comment: I had some retina problems as well with iphone 5 and I remember that I read that if this file is missing than iphone 5 screen will not be supported by cocos2d. Probably they fixed it by now ...

Comment: Is retina mode of CCDirector enabled?

Comment: @Kreiri derp. Nope, it wasn't. For some reason, despite reading all the documentation, I just assumed that the default was YES.